# Is $\overline{x_1,x_2}$ the appropriate way to write the average of $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Tags: notation, average

Simple question of style: if I want to use an overbar to denote the arithmetic mean of two specific numbers, $x_1$ and $x_2$, do I have to enclose them in parentheses, or braces, or anything?

Or is it simply $\overline{x_1,x_2}$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably better to write out $(x_1+x_2)/2$ to avoid confusion.

Comment: Your best option is probably $\overline{x}$, since the mean is a operation on the family and not the individual terms of it.  But, if you're writing formally, you'd want to specify that that's what you mean.

Comment: `\overline{x_1,x_2}` is 18 characters, while `(x_1+x_2)/2` is 11.

Comment: If I so $\overline{x_1,x_2}$ I would not know what you meant.  But if I saw $<\overline{x_1,x_2}>$ or $(\overline{x_1,x_2})$ then ... I still wouldn't know what you meant.  ....But if I were taking a class and the text defined the notation ... I'd do what the text said.

Comment: hmm, maybe you all are right. My intention was to save space while labelling a figure, but yes it would be clearer to write it out explicitly as e.g. hardmath says...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you want a terse label on a figure, the better approach would be to use $(x_1 + x_2)/2$ to convey the arithmetic mean of two specified values $x_1$ and $x_2$, or slightly more concise:

$$ \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2} $$

Of course as an author you are free to redefine an overbar to abbreviate whatever meaning is convenient to your exposition.  The trade-off is that you will need to provide that definition to readers because it is unconventional.

What is conventional is the use of an overbar on a random variable to mean its expected value, e.g. $\overline X$ means the expected value $E(X)$.

The concise notation $\overline X$ is attractive when only two outcomes $X = x_1$ and $X = x_2$ are possible and have equal probability. E.g. if we go to the trouble of defining random variable $X$ as a *sample* based on two observations $x_1,x_2$, then $\overline X$ would mean the arithmetic mean of $x_1$ and $x_2$, as you wished.